# 3D Max modifier index confusion

Tags: python, 3dsmax

I have a 3DS Max scene object that I applied a skin wrap modifier to. I want to convert it into a skin modifier, and then delete the skin wrap directly underneath it in the stack.

So I should simply delete the modifier via it's stack number correct?
Heck, I even have a print line that identifies its number in the stack.

I apologize for the back and forth between python and EvalMAXScript, I'm not a coder, just someone struggling to understand.

```
# setup =======================================================

import MaxPlus as mp
from pymxs import runtime as rt

mySel = rt.selection
max = mp.Core.EvalMAXScript

box    = mp.Factory.CreateGeomObject(mp.ClassIds.Box)
sphere = mp.Factory.CreateGeomObject(mp.ClassIds.Sphere)
cyl    = mp.Factory.CreateGeomObject(mp.ClassIds.Cylinder)
node   = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateNode

node(box)
node(sphere)
node(cyl)
#setup =======================================================

max("select #($Sphere001, $Cylinder001)")

# =============================================
rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin())
max("select $Sphere001")
max("skinOps.addBone $.modifiers[#Skin] $Cylinder001 1")
# =============================================

max("select $Box001")

rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin_Wrap())
max("append $" + str(mySel[0].name) +".modifiers[#Skin_Wrap].meshList $Sphere001")
mySel[0].modifiers[0].meshDeformOps.convertToSkin (False) 

print mySel[0].modifiers[0].name + " <----- ZERO"
print mySel[0].modifiers[1].name + " <----- ONE!!!!"
#print mySel[0].modifiers[2].name  #<----- will say IndexError: Index out of range <--- This makes sense

rt.deleteModifier (mySel[0], 2) #<------------------ I want to delete the SKIN WRAP modifier SO WHY 2???
```

But then why does deleting the skin wrap modifier require "2" in the deleteModifer arg??

When printing out the name of the modifier, does 3Ds Max a different numbering order from when you delete it?

Does this have anything to do with the fact that python counts/iterations start from 0 and not 1?

Can someone point me / or anyone who would like to learn scripting in max with python to a document where I could get the info about something like this? Because I imagine that something as common as putting in the correct index number should be somewhere in some basic documentation (which I obviously failed to find).

Pardon the angst. I've been up for hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working until I accidentally stumbled upon putting an out of range index number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[according to the doc](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/3DSMax-MAXScript/files/GUID-DB496ACA-1506-4FB1-B8F8-EECC7D9794DD-htm.html), you can directly pass the modifier instead of the index to the `deleteModifier` function :

`deleteModifier <node> <modifier_or_index>`

So something like that can work:

```py
import MaxPlus as mp
from pymxs import runtime as rt

mySel = rt.selection
max = mp.Core.EvalMAXScript

node   = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateNode
box = mp.Factory.CreateGeomObject(mp.ClassIds.Box)

node_box = node(box) # Watch out, 'node_box' this is a MaxPlus node

max("select $Box001")

# Create the modifiers
rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin_Wrap()) # Skin Wrap
rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin()) # Skin

# Get their references
modifier_skin      = mySel[0].modifiers[0]
modifier_skin_wrap = mySel[0].modifiers[1]

print (modifier_skin.name + " <----- modifier_skin")
print (modifier_skin_wrap.name + " <----- modifier_skin_wrap")

rt.deleteModifier (mySel[0], modifier_skin_wrap)
rt.deleteModifier (mySel[0], modifier_skin)
```

You can even do a function which can delete a modifier for a given name:

```py
import MaxPlus as mp
from pymxs import runtime as rt

def delete_modifier_by_name(node, modifier_name):
    max_node = rt.getnodebyname(node.Name)
    for modifier in max_node.modifiers:
        if modifier.name == modifier_name:
            print("Deleting %s..." % modifier.name)
            rt.deleteModifier (max_node, modifier)
            return

mySel = rt.selection
max = mp.Core.EvalMAXScript

node   = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateNode
box = mp.Factory.CreateGeomObject(mp.ClassIds.Box)

node_box = node(box) # Watch out, 'node_box' this is a MaxPlus node

max("select $Box001")

# Create the modifiers
rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin_Wrap()) # Skin Wrap
rt.addModifier (mySel[0], rt.Skin()) # Skin

delete_modifier_by_name(node_box, "Skin")
#~ delete_modifier_by_name(node_box, "Skin Wrap")
```